# Should we remove the flag "not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, support

A problem with "not an answer" is that the answer is usually not "bad" enough to warrant being deleted by a moderator.

Perhaps we should remove this flag option.  I noticed stackoverflow.com itself doesn't have this flag option.  If we do want to remove it, how do we do so?  (searched a lot and unable to find)

Answer (score 1):

The "*Not an Answer*" flag is not for bad answers.  A moderator should decline flags used this way.

The flag is intended to be used for posts in the answer field that don't address the question at all.  There is a discussion on the main meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag)

I would suggest that the flag be kept

Comment: "to notify moderators that a posted answer is not an answer, and should be deleted"  Most flaggers seem unaware of the last part "should be deleted" by moderator.  Most of these answers should be downvoted by the community which will get auto-deleted.